# What is Key Ceremony in Cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, aes, smartcard, pki

I tried google, but its not what I want. Google says, its a gathering to check how securely a signing key is stored based on distributed access to the key.

I have this class which has 3 Strings(broken key) and respective attributes (key check values, zone key check values, encryption master key). Using which I derive a Master key. I cannot put up the code here, as it violates my security policy. btw this is for smart cards.

If any one has any idea of this, please explain or point me to it.

Comment: This is not a programming question and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_ceremony) explains it. Also, [Cryptography.SO](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5332/18298) may have the answer for you.

Comment: You may also look at [Information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24896/86735).

Comment: @kelalaka: The wikipedia article is far from being authoritative and flagged accordingly. I agree, that the question lacks programming context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm going to be assuming a simple symmetric key (3DES or AES) split into 3 parts here. I can only answer *because* I make this assumption.

A key value is randomly generated, this is the key you're going to protect. Lets call this key the master key. A KCV (key check value) is calculated over the master key, so if it is regenerated the correctness of the key can be verified with relatively high certainty without revealing the value itself. The KCV doesn't leak information about the key material itself as the calculation of the KCV is *one way*.

This key is split into three parts using other random values and XOR. First *two* other random keys are generated. The third key is calculated to be the XOR of the other keys *and* the master key. KCV values are calculated and written down. The three keys can now be distributed to 3 different actors. These actors are called key managers in the role they perform in the ceremony. Commonly the key managers secure access to their key.

Now to regenerate the master key each key manager writes down their part of the key. The KCV of the key is verified before proceeding to make sure that no input errors have been mode, or that the value is not that of a different key. Now if you calculate the XOR of the three keys then you'll get the master key again. This value is again compared to the master key.

So that's all there is to it.

---

With regards to the security of this scheme:

- you need all three keys as the other keys basically provide a One-Time-Pad encryption over the key value, which provides a very strong notion of security
- the common KCV is a dangerous notion, as an encryption of an all zero block - the most common scheme - may leak sensitive information (e.g. for counter mode security with a zero nonce and counter). E.g. a HMAC over an empty value may be a better idea
- obviously you need a secure random number generator to generate the keys or your scheme is likely to be insecure
- it will be hard to generate the wrong key on purpose; commonly the KCV is three bytes, so the chance of one or two people colluding and generate the KCV of the master key is 1 in 2^24 (2^24 is over 16 million).

Answer (score 0):

Key Ceremony in cryptography means that how you will activate your Signing key for different purpose like CA key when issuing a certificate. Key Ceremony have very strong security level that a key is activate with m of n rule, key is stored on secure physical location in Laptops or in HSM(hardware to store keys).
For more detail see **WebTrust Principles and Criteria for Certification Authorities – v2.2** document ,download from http://www.webtrust.org/principles-and-criteria/docs/item83987.pdf, in section 4.4 **CA Key Usage**

Answer (score 0):

On a high level, It's a process of rotating the cryptography keys on Production/UAT environment between two entities and then one entity send a request to another entity to make a session between them with the help of the keys. Keys can have certain roles to encrypt/decrypt the message, to check the integrity of the message e.t.c.